# Sitecore Experience Editor Popup Window

Tags: experience-editor, speak, sheer-ui

I want to add a button to EE edit frame so that when clicked it will open a popup window with some custom data/fieldValue.

For example, when you click "Usage: " button at the end of the edit frame menu.

[image]

How to achieve this..

Comment: What version of speak are you using?

Comment: on sitecore 9.0

Answer (score 1):

You can add a DialogWindow component on your app's presentation details.

In your javascript add a function to open the dialog window.

```
openUploadDialog: function () {
  this.UploadDialog.show();
},
```

Then, you can call this function with a button or other trigger.

[image]